# How does E-commerce platforms with microservices architecture use Redis for Caching?

Tags: express, rest, redis, microservices, web-application-design

I am using Microservice architecture in my application.Whenever server gets the request,it has to fetch the data from Database,which takes hell lot of time (and inefficient too),So I want to implement caching using Redis for faster accessing.In Case of Microservices architecure,for Caching Do I have to implement Redis cache in each Microservice ? Or Is there any other way to do this?

I have just learnt about Redis,and I am hoping someone would help me get clarity on this,Since I want to implement Caching for my Application!

Answer (score 0):

You have two main choices for implementing Redis caching in microservices:

- Implement a separate Redis cache for each microservice. It's like
  each service has its own quick-access memory, but this could lead to
  duplicated data across services.
- Use one Redis cache shared by all services. This is more
  memory-efficient and avoids data duplication, but requires careful
  management to avoid becoming a bottleneck.

Individual caching is simpler and keeps services independent, but might waste memory. Centralized caching is more efficient and consistent, but can be complex and risky if it fails. The best approach depends on your application's specific and real life needs and might involve a combination of both strategies.